# Kill process on port 80

Tags: command-line, apache2

Hi 'yall I tried running this command on my terminal to kill the tcp process so I can start my apache service. But it's seem there's some kind of mistakes. Here is the result and the command line I've tried to use.

```
trainee@sysad:~$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
sudo: unable to resolve host sysad
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      998/httpd       
trainee@sysad:~$ sudo killall -9 80/tcp6
sudo: unable to resolve host sysad
80/tcp6: No such file or directory
trainee@sysad:~$ sudo killall -9 tcp6
sudo: unable to resolve host sysad
tcp6: no process found
trainee@sysad:~$ sudo killall -9 tcp6/80
sudo: unable to resolve host sysad
tcp6/80: No such file or directory
trainee@sysad:~$ sudo killall -9 16085
sudo: unable to resolve host sysad
16085: no process found
```

And when I run my httpd service. Here's what it says:

```
trainee@sysad:~$ sudo service httpd start
sudo: unable to resolve host sysad
httpd: Syntax error on line 53 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: libmysqlclient.so.18:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thank you so much in advance.

I'll answer my own problem:

Here's what I typed though:

```
$ sudo kill 998
```

Just like in my case when I reboot my system, I got the same error. Then typed the command:

```
   trainee@sysad:~$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      <number>/httpd
```

Then the number will be different. Then I altered the sudo kill like:

```
 $sudo kill <number>
```

Well it worked for me though. I don't know to others(you) if it works as well :)

Comment: your problem is a syntax error in your config file, read the error message. "httpd: Syntax error on line 53 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: libmysqlclient.so.18:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: I'll answer my own problem.
Here's what I tried on my command-line (It worked for me, I don't know to others)

    $ sudo kill 998

Comment: @user3335903 Don't simply answer your question with a comment. If you've got an answer, please post it and accept it. This may help others who have a similar problem.